# Javascript - How to get element that was clicked

Tags: javascript, function

I'm making a really simple photo gallery with thumbnails and I have a working code which changes the big image when a thumbnail is clicked. Now what I need is to add a green border to the thumbnail which is currently active.

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div id="big">
        <img align="center" src="big/pipe_big.jpg" alt="" id="image" />
    </div>
    <div id="small">
        <img onclick="changeImage('pipe')" src="small/pipe_small.jpg" alt="" />
        <img onclick="changeImage('leaves')" src="small/leaves_small.jpg" alt="" />
        <img onclick="changeImage('orange')" src="small/orange_small.jpg" alt="" />
        <img onclick="changeImage('xuangong')" src="small/xuangong_small.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="small">
        <img onclick="changeImage('grave')" src="small/grave_small.jpg" alt="" />
        <img onclick="changeImage('lotus')" src="small/lotus_small.jpg" alt="" />
        <img onclick="changeImage('tibet_girl')" src="small/tibet_girl_small.jpg" alt="" />
        <img onclick="changeImage('girl_water')" src="small/girl_water_small.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function changeImage(x){
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    var active_image = ??????????

    if (x == 'pipe') {
        image.src = 'big/pipe_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'leaves') {
        image.src = 'big/leaves_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'orange') {
        image.src = 'big/orange_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'xuangong') {
        image.src = 'big/xuangong_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'grave') {
        image.src = 'big/grave_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'lotus') {
        image.src = 'big/lotus_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'tibet_girl') {
        image.src = 'big/tibet_girl_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'girl_water') {
        image.src = 'big/girl_water_big.jpg';
    }
    active_image.style.border = '2px solid green';
}
```

So I need to find the element that triggered the function and put it into variable "active_image" so that the function "changeImage()" always changes the border to 2px solid green. And please no jQuery solutions, I need it to be JavaScript.

Comment: " I need it to be JavaScript", then use JS and [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), not HTML.

Comment: Would it not be easier to use a class and loop through it rather than the if/else if statement? Also onload events will slim back on your html...?

Comment: It will be a big change in your source code but it will remove the old border. This is why i'm asking before submitting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll( "#gallery img" );
for( i =0; i< images.length; i++ ) {
    images[i].style.border = "0px";
}
var active_image = event.target;
```

Comment: This worked for getting the green border after an image was clicked. I still need to remove that border if another image is clicked but I can't seem to figure out what I should do

Comment: I forgot to mention that the other thumbnails are getting a red 2px border when I put my mouse over them (img: hover{border:2px solid red}. But when the JS changes the style it removes the hover effect...

Comment: You can create a css class for the selected thumbnails, and add/remove that class in the event handler e.g. images[i].classList.remove('selected') or active_image.classList.add('selected')

Comment: Can't get it to work... I'm getting really frustrated with this. It's a school task and our teacher expects us to know how to make this kind of scripts even though he hasn't taught us Javascript at all...

Comment: Try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/bdomokos74/vLucuyob/ You need to find out these things yourself, there are a lot of resources out there..

Comment: I really appreciate the help and I've been working on this gallery 6 hours today. I'm still a real beginner with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the function calls to include 'this' as the second parameter:

```
<div id="gallery">
<div id="big">
    <img align="center" src="big/pipe_big.jpg" alt="" id="image" />
</div>
<div id="small">
    <img id="img1" onclick="changeImage('pipe',this)" src="small/pipe_small.jpg" alt="" />
    <img id="img2" onclick="changeImage('leaves',this)" src="small/leaves_small.jpg" alt="" />
    <img id="img3" onclick="changeImage('orange',this)" src="small/orange_small.jpg" alt="" />
    <img id="img4" onclick="changeImage('xuangong',this)" src="small/xuangong_small.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="small">
    <img id="img5" onclick="changeImage('grave',this)" src="small/grave_small.jpg" alt="" />
    <img id="img6" onclick="changeImage('lotus',this)" src="small/lotus_small.jpg" alt="" />
    <img id="img7" onclick="changeImage('tibet_girl',this)" src="small/tibet_girl_small.jpg" alt="" />
    <img id="img8" onclick="changeImage('girl_water',this)" src="small/girl_water_small.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

And the dom element will be available in the function. So your function becomes:

```
var active_element_id;
function changeImage(x,element){
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    var active_image = element.src;

    if (x == 'pipe') {
        image.src = 'big/pipe_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'leaves') {
        image.src = 'big/leaves_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'orange') {
        image.src = 'big/orange_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'xuangong') {
        image.src = 'big/xuangong_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'grave') {
    image.src = 'big/grave_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'lotus') {
        image.src = 'big/lotus_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'tibet_girl') {
        image.src = 'big/tibet_girl_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'girl_water') {
        image.src = 'big/girl_water_big.jpg';
    }
    if(active_element_id){
        var active_element = document.getElementById(active_element_id);
        active_element.style.border = '0px solid green';
    }
    element.style.border = '2px solid green';
    active_element_id = element.getAttribute('id');
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. No green border after I click on an image

Comment: Yeah just change 'active_image.style.border' to 'element.style.border'.

Comment: That worked! Now I just need to remove that border if another image is clicked. Currently it applies the border whenever an image is clicked but it stays there if another one is clicked. Thanks for helping me

Comment: The edited solution code should do what you're looking for. Give each image element an id and will save the id of the last image clicked. When you click an image it clears the border of the previous image clicked.

Comment: It does work, but only once. If I click on all of the images once, it won't give the hover effect anymore :/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a green border to the element which is currently being hovered over, by using `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` as well as `this.style.borderColor` to change the color:

```
<img onmouseover="this.style.borderColor='green'" onmouseout="this.style.borderColor='black'" onclick="changeImage('pipe')" src="small/pipe_small.jpg" alt="" />
```

Working Example:

```css
div {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
    border-color: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="this.style.borderColor='green'" onmouseout="this.style.borderColor='black'"></div><br>
<div onmouseover="this.style.borderColor='green'" onmouseout="this.style.borderColor='black'"></div><br><div onmouseover="this.style.borderColor='green'" onmouseout="this.style.borderColor='black'"></div><br><div onmouseover="this.style.borderColor='green'" onmouseout="this.style.borderColor='black'"></div><br><div onmouseover="this.style.borderColor='green'" onmouseout="this.style.borderColor='black'"></div><br><div onmouseover="this.style.borderColor='green'" onmouseout="this.style.borderColor='black'"></div><br><div onmouseover="this.style.borderColor='green'" onmouseout="this.style.borderColor='black'"></div><br>
```

Comment: I need the border when the element is clicked, not hovered over. I could do that with just CSS

Answer (score 0):

#### [Plunkr Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/3QxYpMiO7iSnehu9PhnE?p=preview)

The way with least changes to your code:

```
function changeImage(x){
    var active_image = this;
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    
    var images = [],
        containers = document.getElementsByClassName('small');
    for (var i=0,n=containers.length; i < n; i++){
       var imgs = containers[i].getElementsByTagName('img');
       for (var j=0,m=imgs.length; j < m; j++ ){
         images = images.concat(imgs[j]);
       }
    }

    if (x == 'pipe') {
        image.src = 'big/pipe_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'leaves') {
        image.src = 'big/leaves_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'orange') {
        image.src = 'big/orange_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'xuangong') {
        image.src = 'big/xuangong_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'grave') {
        image.src = 'big/grave_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'lotus') {
        image.src = 'big/lotus_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'tibet_girl') {
        image.src = 'big/tibet_girl_big.jpg';
    } else if (x == 'girl_water') {
        image.src = 'big/girl_water_big.jpg';
    }
    // reset border
    for (var i=0,n=images.length;i<n;i++){
      images[i].style.border = '0px solid green';
    }
    // set active border
    active_image.style.border = '2px solid green';
}
```

Note you cannot have two elements with the same ID (e.g., `small`), so you must use a class, or change the ID to a unique name.

Also see that if you use the `call()` method, you can pass along what `this` is.  In this case, it's important because you want to pass along the element that is being clicked.  So for `onclick="<function name>.call(this)"`, the `this` is that element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="gallery">
    <div id="big">
        <img align="center" src="big/pipe_big.jpg" alt="" id="image" />
    </div>
    <div class="small">
        <img onclick="changeImage.call(this,'pipe')"       src="small/pipe_small.jpg" alt="" />
        <img onclick="changeImage.call(this,'leaves')"     src="small/leaves_small.jpg" alt="" />
        <img onclick="changeImage.call(this,'orange')"     src="small/orange_small.jpg" alt="" />
        <img onclick="changeImage.call(this,'xuangong')"   src="small/xuangong_small.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="small">
        <img onclick="changeImage.call(this,'grave')"      src="small/grave_small.jpg" alt="" />
        <img onclick="changeImage.call(this,'lotus')"      src="small/lotus_small.jpg" alt="" />
        <img onclick="changeImage.call(this,'tibet_girl')" src="small/tibet_girl_small.jpg" alt="" />
        <img onclick="changeImage.call(this,'girl_water')" src="small/girl_water_small.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

#### Big Note

There is much more you could do to your code to make it more scalable and efficient, this is only a starter answer, without confusing you too much.  Please keep at, keep learning and expanding your knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `this` inside an event handler to get the element. However, since you use inline event handlers, inside `changeImage`, `this` will be another value (you could still pass it using `call`, `apply`, or as an argument).

However, better avoid inline event listeners:

```js
var image = document.getElementById('image'),
    images = document.getElementById('small').getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i=0; i<images.length; ++i)
  images[i].addEventListener('click', changeImage);

function changeImage(){
  var x = this.getAttribute('data-img');
  image.src = 'big/' + x + '_big.jpg';
  this.style.border = '2px solid green';
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <div id="big">
    <img align="center" src="big/pipe_big.jpg" alt="" id="image" />
  </div>
  <div id="small">
    <img data-img="pipe" src="small/pipe_small.jpg" alt="" />
    <img data-img="leaves" src="small/leaves_small.jpg" alt="" />
    <img data-img="orange" src="small/orange_small.jpg" alt="" />
    <img data-img="xuangong" src="small/xuangong_small.jpg" alt="" />
    <img data-img="grave" src="small/grave_small.jpg" alt="" />
    <img data-img="lotus" src="small/lotus_small.jpg" alt="" />
    <img data-img="tibet_girl" src="small/tibet_girl_small.jpg" alt="" />
    <img data-img="girl_water" src="small/girl_water_small.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```